# mysql Insert Statements in Stored Procedure not Inserting

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert, sql-insert

I created a stored procedure which should perform the following:
Insert into Agencies Table, creating an id in the PK index row
Save the id in a variable
Insert the id and other data into Users table

The syntax below does not trigger any errors:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insertNewAgencyAndAdmin (IN aName varchar (100), IN numTrav int, IN polType int, IN uEmail varchar(255), IN uFName varchar(40), IN uLName varchar(40), IN uTitle varchar(100))
BEGIN

INSERT INTO btsAgency.Agencies (agencyName, numTrav, polType) VALUES (@aName, @numTrav, @polType);

SET @agencyID = (SELECT agencyID from btsAgency.Agencies where agencyID = LAST_INSERT_ID());

INSERT INTO btsUsers.Users (userAgencyID, userEmail, userFirstName, userLastName, userTitle ) VALUES 
(@agencyID, @uEmail, @uFName, @uLName, @uTitle);

END
```

However, the Stored Proc doesn't insert my parameters into the tables when executed. So, after searching I try to create the SP like this (including $$ after "END" and resetting the delimiter to  a semi-colon ):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insertNewAgencyAndAdmin (IN aName varchar (100), IN numTrav int, IN polType int, IN uEmail varchar(255), IN uFName varchar(40), IN uLName varchar(40), IN uTitle varchar(100))
BEGIN

INSERT INTO btsAgency.Agencies (agencyName, numTrav, polType) VALUES (@aName, @numTrav, @polType);

SET @agencyID = (SELECT agencyID from btsAgency.Agencies where agencyID = LAST_INSERT_ID());

INSERT INTO btsUsers.Users (userAgencyID, userEmail, userFirstName, userLastName, userTitle ) VALUES 
(@agencyID, @uEmail, @uFName, @uLName, @uTitle);

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

MySql creates the Stored Proc but gives me the following error:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

When I execute the created Stored Proc it still doesn't insert the data in my parameters.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems in your stored procedure:

- It is important to indicate the difference between [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) and routine parameters [13.1.15. CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html), are different variables (eg.: `aName` != `@aName`).
- Avoid naming parameters or variables as columns of your tables.

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `insertNewAgencyAndAdmin` (
  /*    
  IN `aName` varchar (100),
  IN `numTrav` int,
  IN `polType` int,
  IN `uEmail` varchar(255),
  IN `uFName` varchar(40),
  IN `uLName` varchar(40),
  IN `uTitle` varchar(100)
  */
  IN `_aName` varchar (100),
  IN `_numTrav` int,
  IN `_polType` int,
  IN `_uEmail` varchar(255),
  IN `_uFName` varchar(40),
  IN `_uLName` varchar(40),
  IN `_uTitle` varchar(100)
)
BEGIN
  /*  
  INSERT INTO `btsAgency`.`Agencies` (
    `agencyName`,
    `numTrav`,
    `polType`
  ) VALUES (
    @`aName`,
    @`numTrav`,
    @`polType`
  );
  */    
  INSERT INTO `btsAgency`.`Agencies` (
    `agencyName`,
    `numTrav`,
    `polType`
  ) VALUES (
    `_aName`,
    `_numTrav`,
    `_polType`
  );    
  /*
  SET @`agencyID` = (SELECT `agencyID` from `btsAgency`.`Agencies` where `agencyID` = LAST_INSERT_ID());

  INSERT INTO `btsUsers`.`Users` (
    `userAgencyID`,
    `userEmail`,
    `userFirstName`,
    `userLastName`,
    `userTitle`
  ) VALUES (
    @`agencyID`,
    @`uEmail`,
    @`uFName`,
    @`uLName`,
    @`uTitle`
  );
  */    
  INSERT INTO `btsUsers`.`Users` (
    `userAgencyID`,
    `userEmail`,
    `userFirstName`,
    `userLastName`,
    `userTitle`
  ) VALUES (
    LAST_INSERT_ID(),
    `_uEmail`,
    `_uFName`,
    `_uLName`,
    `_uTitle`);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM discounts $$
delimiter $$; 
CREATE PROCEDURE insertData(IN id int,IN title varchar(255),IN amount decimal)
BEGIN

insert into discounts values (id,title,amount);
END; $$
call insertData(3,"sadasd",56);

/*DROP PROCEDURE insertData */